# How to compute the scalar product from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I hope you guys are well.

I have an array of date,

Link of the data ([enter link description here](https://mega.nz/#!UQcTUQCC!l-fvFSf2dcpqs7wAsoHvudOPdFtkXonW43ErrjbrxJs))

I want to calculate the scalar product without repeating or counting twice. I mean,

```
scalarproduct = np.dot (chiunitvdt1[i],chiunitvdt1[j])
```

I we suppose "chiunitvdt1" has only 4 datas, we see that the differents scalars products (without repeating) are:

```
 np.dot (chiunitvdt1[0],chiunitvdt1[1]), np.dot (chiunitvdt1[0],chiunitvdt1[2]), np.dot (chiunitvdt1[0],chiunitvdt1[3]),
    np.dot (chiunitvdt1[1],chiunitvdt1[2]),np.dot (chiunitvdt1[1],chiunitvdt1[3]),
    np.dot (chiunitvdt1[2],chiunitvdt1[3])
```

I am using,

```
scalarproduct=[]
for i in range(0,len(chiunitvdt1)): 
    for j in range(i+1,len(dt1)): #"j" runs as i+1
        angle=abs(np.dot(chiunitvdt1[i],chiunitvdt1[j]))
        scalarproduct.append(angle)
```

But I think that I am only counting

```
[0][1], [1],[2], [2],[3],...
and not [0][2],[0][3],..., [1][3],...
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it (**minimal** example) as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ... [mcve]

Comment: You can produce the indices combinations with `itertools.combinations(range(n_datas),2)`